# Re-enabling Messenger in Outlook 2003

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office-communicator-2007, communicator

I have Outlook 2003 and have lost the messenger functionality. It was working up until I tried to install Communicator 2007. Communicator failed to connect to the server so I un-installed it and assumed it would go back to using Windows Messenger like it was before. Instead I now can not login to messenger via Outlook, there is not even the option to do so. I am not sure what program handles this, I assume it is Windows Messenger. I have tried installing the latest Live Messenger but that does not help. Does anyone have any ideas or anywhere I can download Messenger 2003?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Live_Messenger), you are probably looking for Messenger from when it was called MSN Messenger and was version 6. Here are a few download links :

[MSN Messenger 6.2.0208](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Chat/Instant-Messaging/MSN-Messenger-6.shtml)
[MSN Messenger for Windows 2000 6.1](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Chat/Instant-Messaging/MSN-Messenger-for-Windows.shtml) (probably not your version)

However, as your version of Office seems to be loused-up, what I would recommend instead is uninstalling Office entirely, deleting its folder in Program Files, then re-installing from scratch.

That's assuming that you have on hand the installation media **and** the serial number of your Office version. If you don't, then let me know.

I would also take a backup image of the system drive before starting, just in case that the Office re-installation fails.